# Android Fragment onactivity result null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

I am android beginner, my aim is select image and display on my ImageView, I use below code but in fragment onActivity result return null pointer exception.

This is my fragmentA.java

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);


    switch(requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PHOTO:
            if(resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

                    Log.v("imageUri", imageUri.toString());

                    final InputStream imageStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                    final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    image.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            initImage();
            break;
    }
}
```

I used below code for call gallery intent

```
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT )
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PHOTO);

            }
            else
            {
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
            }


        }
    });
```

This is my error report ..

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {citycenter.caneda.com.citycenter/com.caneda.citycenter.myaccount.AccountMainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/506 }} to activity {citycenter.caneda.com.citycenter/com.caneda.citycenter.myaccount.AccountMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException


 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/506 }} to activity {citycenter.caneda.com.citycenter/com.caneda.citycenter.myaccount.AccountMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException


 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.caneda.citycenter.myaccount.FragmentTabProfile.onActivityResult(FragmentTabProfile.java:217)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:163)
        at com.caneda.citycenter.myaccount.AccountMainActivity.onActivityResult(AccountMainActivity.java:102)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5305)
```

Comment: I tired this library as well..

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-fix-nested-fragment-onactivityresult-issue/en?fb_action_ids=780839882030502&fb_action_types=og.comments

Comment: Probably `imageReturnedIntent` is null

Answer (score 0):

I think the line

```
resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK
```

is causing the problem
USE

```
resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK
```

because RESULT_OK is static

However you can debug to test which code is causing NullPointerException

Comment: This line cause the error..

image.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);

Answer (score -1):

Actully answer is really silly, I have initialize
conditional based

```
if(saveInstaceState == null) { ivUpload  = (ImageView) }
```

It should be outside of condition.

That's why it cause `nullPointerException` by ivUpload.

Thanks you so much for you support.